how do you pair amplifiers and speakers?
Contradicting rules of thumb:

amp should be 2x speaker wattage so the amp doesn't struggle
speakers should be slightly higher rating so they don't blow up

In stereo systems or any combo of amp and speakers put together by a manufacturer, I've never seen an amp that was double the speaker wattage but not pushing the amp seems like a legitimate theory.
That also means that you would need to be aware of your volume at all times to save your speakers.
the opposite could be said for protecting the amplifier with high power speakers though. you could technically run the amp at 100% which would shorten its life span, I think.
which way is better, in general, for a stable combination that will last?
EDIT: Here's a couple of references to show my confusion:
Note: these are summarized and not directly quoted from their sources. Links provided.
Matching Speakers With Amps As Far As Wattage? - InSync

normally recommend around twice as much amplifier power as speaker’s power rating. the idea is to have enough clean power to handle whatever you throw at the amp without clipping.
the extra power is to be kept in reserve so the amp can deal with peaks and transients without clipping.

How to Match a Cab to Your Head - InSync

speaker cabinet’s power handling must match or exceed the maximum output power of the amp head. If the power handling of the speaker is too low, then you may damage your cabinet, amplifier, or both.


Is this for guitar or bass or for a PA system. For PA speakers, be aware that you should have at least two power ratings listed the specs: peak and continuous dissipation.

guitar, bass, PA, and HIFI AV Receiver. Program means RMS does it?

Guitar, bass, hifi, and PA systems all have different configuration goals. Asking about all four in one question is too broad. I think hifi might be off topic. You can probably lump guitar and bass together and have PA be a separate question. So I suggest you choose between guitar/bass and PA.

@ToddWilcox sorry i had no idea how to answer that, is there much difference between guitar/bass and PA, I am more interested in powering speakers for a PA but I also need to know about guitar/bass applications. is the difference because PA speaker cabinets have for example woofers and horns hooked up to one input?

I've realized my "answer" wasn't an answer, so I'm going to give you a few guidelines for matching for a small PA:

Choose speakers first based on the system design goals. Only choose speakers that have complete published specs. At minimum, you need frequency response (3 dB down points), sensitivity (dB SPL @1W/1m), continuous, program, and peak power dissipation ratings (in Watts), maximum SPL, and nominal load impedance. These JBL specs are a good example. I personally wouldn't buy anything that did not have all those specs publicly available.
When matching the power amp, if you want a simple guide, try to find an amp that has maximum power matching the rated program dissipation of the speakers at the nominal load impedance.
The main limiting factors you'll run up against are cost and weight. The best stuff is more expensive and heavier. You can deal with weight by buying a system with a larger number of lighter components, but that will cost you more in the end and be harder to set up.
If you buy an amp that has power capability lower than the program rating of the speakers, the negative consequence is that you paid for capability in your speakers that you can't realize using your amp. The positive consequence is you have more leeway for unexpected peaks to not cause over-excursion of the drivers.
If you buy an amp that has a power capability higher than the program rating of the speakers, then you overbought the amp and you are more capable of accidentally overheating the drivers or causing over-excursion. The positive consequence is more system headroom and possible lower audible self-noise, as long as you're careful about your levels.
Some engineers will warn against buying an underpowered amp for an additional reason. They theorize that when you buy too little amp, you're more likely to turn up all your levels, to the point of overdriving your amp into clipping. IMHO if you can't hear your amp clipping and have the maturity to back down, your primary problem is not that you underbought your amp, it's that you have no business running live sound. In any case, clipping adds power bandwidth, up to double the Watts going through the speakers. This won't increase the risk of over-excursion but causes much higher than expected heating of drivers which can lead to failure.

Overall, it's not a simple thing. When you combine all the considerations of cost, weight, damping factor, power ratings (three different kinds), bandwidth & power bandwidth, impedance, etc., etc., it's really much easier to buy powered systems. You can easily design a system these days that doesn't need an FOH rack or an analog snake.
Revisiting some points from your question:


amp should be 2x speaker wattage so the amp doesn't struggle

speakers should be slightly higher rating so they don't blow up



Both wrong. Just ignore both of these points. Neither is helpful. The first one is nonsense and the second one isn't precise enough to do you any good.

you could technically run the amp at 100% which would shorten its life span, I think.

Not really. If you run your amps hot the things that will fail first are your speakers, not your amps. Solid state amps can handle a lot. If you underload them, that can easily shorten their lifespans. If you don't provide adequate ventilation, that can shorten their lifespans. If they are cheap and poorly made, then running them hotter might shorten their lifespans. A QSC or Crown amp run "at 100%" with appropriate load impedances attached and ventilation should last for years. But most amps won't sound very good running "at 100%", so for other reasons, this is not a good plan.
Source: I designed, built, and ran small PA systems professionally for about 15 years.

I’m curious your source for this “rule”:

amp should be 2x speaker wattage so the amp doesn't struggle

Because it makes no sense. Why would the amp’s nominal output capacity being less than the connected speaker’s rated dissipation cause the amp to “struggle”?
The problem with running an amp “at 100%” is not that it would wear out the amp, but that the clipping would essentially double the actual power that had to be dissipated by the speaker system.
If you want to design a system that is loud enough, sounds good, can be operated safely and does not destroy itself during normal use, you’ll have to learn a lot more than can be relayed in a stack exchange answer.
Or you can just buy powered speakers and not have to worry about any of it.

why would clipping double the power? it wouldn't need to be at 100% if it was double the power of the speakers

@yarns I don’t know all of the electrical engineering myself but two people have told you the same thing. Another answer says this “Now when a solid state amp starts clipping, the ratio of high frequency power it delivers becomes much higher than what would correspond to pink noise (which essentially has constant power per octave).”

I've probably got less of an understanding, I'm not saying they're wrong, i've read it elsewhere too. I gotta catch up, went MIA for a bit. think i gotta go over the white/pink noise bit BRB

i've used the powered speakers solution because it's, well, self explanatory, works out of the box. i've got alot of speakers and amps though and i'm scared to mix and match but i really want to :D this is why i'm trying to learn about it

does underload mean having it quiet or speakers with lower impedance? just another note, i've been putting on gigs out the front of my place with everything i've got so it's a frankenstein and i definately have alot of experience playing guitar and plugging guitar leads into systems somebody else calculated :D. should be enough info to stop me from doing any damage. one of the beasts is a traynor mono bloc-b, solid state from the 70's, indestructable so far... one speaker wasn't

one speaker wasn't, oh that's why i was commenting, i was running 2x 500w 4Ω speakers in parallell when the amp takes 2Ω load, it got hot so i thought wiring them in series or getting new speakers would be better. I can't tell what the specs are, very vague as usual for most brands. i have 2x 15" 8Ω altec-lansing (jbl kinda) speakers from the same era for it

Matching Speakers With Amps As Far As Wattage? - InSync here's one i found finally

and this one (note just for reference, i don't have an opinion on these links) How to Match a Cab to Your Head - InSync
speaker cabinet’s power handling must match or exceed the maximum output power of the amp head. If the power handling of the speaker is too low, then you may damage your cabinet, amplifier, or both.

@yarns Stack Exchange isn’t school. It’s not meant for general education. It’s meant to helping you solve specific problems. Questions about general knowledge can easily be too broad and not a good fit for SE. So if you’re working on a specific project and have a specific problem, then updating your question with those specifics will help us give you a specific answer. If you’re just seeking general knowledge, then I hope my answer gives you some ideas of what to read further and beyond that I don’t know what else to write. Except: Just use powered cabs and don’t bother with all this.

yeah it definately did, and i got some powered wedges and a Peavey XR8600D with matching PV215s which are built to go together. Every time I dive into it I find different answers but they all seemed simple enough so I thought the answer would be simple and it just wasn't sinking in. I've also had trouble writing questions that aren't too specific but I should be right this time. I hope.

I originally posted this as comments on Todd Wilcox's answer but it was a bit of a heavy read so thought I'd add a supplemental answer instead.
This is directly in reference to the OP's comment "why would clipping double the power?".
The RMS power output of a signal is, taking V as the voltage and I as the current of the signal;
(1) P_RMS = V_RMS * I_RMS * cos(theta_V - theta_I)
Where theta_V and theta_I are just the different phases of the voltage and current sinusoids (meaning sin or cosine shaped waves) of a given signal.
When the phase is aligned (ie for a purely resistive load) the cos term = 1, meaning we can ignore it. This probably isn't the case in real life but let's not worry about that here.
For a sin wave, which is a good enough test signal for a rough estimate V_RMS = V_max / sqrt(2) and I_RMS = I_max / sqrt(2)
So if phases are aligned;
(2) P_RMS (sin wave) = V_max / sqrt(2) * I_max / sqrt(2) = (V_max * I_max) / 2
For a square wave (heavily clipped) it's V_RMS and I_RMS is just V_max and I_max, so the above formula (1) for in phase current and voltage for a square wave is
(3) P_RMS (square wave) = V_max * I_max
Compare this (3) to the formula for P_RMS of a sin wave (2), this is where double power comes from for a clipped signal. Essentially, larger area under curves = more RMS power.
Of course real audio will not be a test sin and the clipped audio will not be a perfect square wave, but thats where the roughly double power figure comes from. An amp may be able to output a clipped signal quite happily without burning out, so here is where an underpowered amp could surprise you with damage to speakers rated only just above the amps capabilities.
Conversely, it's true the amp will not reach clipping and the above redundant if it is overpowered for the speakers, but then you risk overdriving the speakers in usual operation, and you may not even hear it until too late. The amp is happy giving out its nice clean signal but it's too much for the speakers to take. What setting of the volume knob will that happen at? For an arbitrarily chosen double-power amplifier that would be hard to tell!
Also you would be paying for amplification you are not going to use, as Todd says. Just match them best as possible with the info in his answer.
An amp, electronically, doesn't need to be overpowered, the amp does not need more watts available in the back pocket to be able to drive a speaker without struggling, that extra energy available will simply not be used. Doing so is, as mentioned, wasting money and adding a little extra potential risk of accidentally overdriving. The circuit doesn't know or care that the amp COULD output more, if it can match the demands of the setup, it should work within spec.
So neither of the two statements are better than the other, the first doesn't really make sense and the second is vague and imprecise. If you want to correctly marry an amp and speaker setup you need to look at the specific specs of each option and choose accordingly.
Sorry for sullying this place with quasi latex, but hopefully it clears up why clipping can hugely increase the power given out to speakers!

no that's kool, because without understanding ( i would have taken your word for it though) then it makes it hard to debate the "rules". now lol, the clipped audio, does that mean clipped before it gets to the input of the amplifier? what about guitar distortion effects? instrument amps are built differently, or was it speakers that were different, i'm confused now, anyways does the clipping refer to the audio being clipped before input to the amp or the output because the amp is cranked too high or both?

@yarns well my answer is just really the maths that shows how much extra power a clipped signal has, this clipping could be from anywhere in the chain. Ie if running a well balanced setup at maximum with a clean signal and then you distort the signal you may well overdrive the speaker. Again it comes down to correctly combining speaker and amp, if it's for guitar and the amp is designed for high gain you need a speaker that can take the power output of this clipped signal. If you are generally not running your setup close to max it should be able to take some clipping.

But you'd need to define the setup and intent of its use to be able to speak more accurately. A clipped signal going in will require higher power capability in all the amp stages compared to a non-clipped signal, but the input signal should be fairly low amplitude so that should be fine. If you are running the amp hot and it starts clipping it's a different story, but this probably means you aren't using a powerful enough amp for the situation. If your amp is fine with outputting the power of a clipped wave you need to match your speaker to be able to receive that power without damage!

yeah it never was a problem, always had headroom, until i started playing outside. open air really sucks the volume. there's too many options i'm considering to discuss here i think

Yeah, playing outside really is a test for even a loud amp. Often the best way is using the help of a PA system and just mic everything up and put through that. Something large enough to do a proper job is big and expensive, of course, so most outdoor events that a large enough would hire one in usually (plus the tech's to run it!). A straight guitar/bass/keyboard amp would need to be really large to keep up. My biggest is a mesa 400+ and even then I think I'd need the 8x10 cab to do a proper job for an average size crowd...

i've got some magnets, 2x pv15-peavey with a xr8600d. 8x12" guitar and 4x15" bass stacks and some smaller amps (roland 200w, fender 500w) with 15" extension cabs

i 4-wired my guitar amp then plugged them all into the stereo outputs on my fx pedal and let her rip out the front of my place, my favourite thing to do

It's an art and a science.
But it isn't rocket surgery.
This article from Sweetwater explains it better than I could ever hope to.
https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/how-to-match-a-cab-to-your-head/

Please include relevant part of the linked material in the answer. See Help Center for information on writing good answers http://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer
